# How do you add one function to work differently in different elements

Tags: html, css, ejs

I am trying to add a search function for every table in my page using jquery and ejs format. It is working when I use 2 same function with different ID. But it seems pointless and waste of time if I repeat the whole function for every table in the page. What do I need to do for this?

This is the code for search function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
       $('#search').keyup(function(){  
            search_table($(this).val());  
       });  
       function search_table(value){  
            $('#table_body tr').each(function(){  
                 var found = 'false';  
                 $(this).each(function(){  
                      if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)  
                      {  
                           found = 'true';  
                      }  
                 });  
                 if(found == 'true')  
                 {  
                      $(this).show();  
                 }  
                 else  
                 {  
                      $(this).hide();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });
```

And this is the ejs code

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="button button1">Add</button>
  <button class="button button2">Edit</button>
  <form action="" class="search-form">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" class="search-input" />
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </form>
</div>
<br />

<table class="table table-sortable" id="pagination">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    <% for(var i=0; i < data.employeeProfile.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= data.employeeProfile[i].name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= data.employeeProfile[i].category %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= data.employeeProfile[i].description %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= data.employeeProfile[i].date %>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <% } %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it should be a reusable code. It's known as DRY ( Do not Repeat Yourself )

So one way of doing this is to create a function which handles the search functionality

Example :

```
function setSearch(inputEle, rowEle){
   $(inputEle).keyup(function(){  
        search_table(rowEle, $(this).val());  
   }); 
} 

function search_table(rowEle, value){  
    $(rowEle).each(function(){  
         var found = 'false';  
         $(this).each(function(){  
             if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)  
             {  
                       found = 'true';  
             }  
         });  
         if(found == 'true')  
         {  
              $(this).show();  
         }  
         else  
         {  
              $(this).hide();  
         }  
    });  
 }
```

Now you can set search functionality by calling setSearch for all the tables like :

```
setSearch('#search', '#table_body tr');
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but when I search, it applies changes to other table at the same time. I want the tables to work differently on the same code. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the EJS code

```
 <div class="topnav">
  <img class="logo-img" src="img/cyberview.png" alt="AVATAR" />
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/home">Home</a>
  <a class="active" href="http://localhost:3000/employee">Employee</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/attendance">Attendance</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/benefit">Benefit</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/calendar">Calendar</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/medical">Medical Portal</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/contracts">Contracts</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/feedback">Feedback</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/rewards">Rewards</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000">Log Out</a>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>Performance</h1>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="button button1">Add</button>
      <button class="button button2">Edit</button>
      <form action="" class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search" class="search-input" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br />

    <table class="table table-sortable" id="pagination">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body">
        <% for(var i=0; i < data.employeeProfile.length; i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].category %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].description %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].date %>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>Personal Information</h1>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="button button1">Add</button>
      <button class="button button2">Edit</button>
      <form action="" class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search" class="search-input" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br />

    <table class="table table-sortable" id="pagination2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Emergency Contact</th>
          <th>Joined Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body">
        <% for(var i=0; i < data.employeeResponse.length; i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].contact %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].email %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].emergencyContact %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].joinedDate %>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code you have provided

```
     function setSearch(inputEle, rowEle){
     $(inputEle).keyup(function(){  
          search_table(rowEle, $(this).val());  
     }); 
  } 
  
  function search_table(rowEle, value){  
      $(rowEle).each(function(){  
           var found = 'false';  
           $(this).each(function(){  
               if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)  
               {  
                         found = 'true';  
               }  
           });  
           if(found == 'true')  
           {  
                $(this).show();  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $(this).hide();  
           }  
      });  
   }  
   setSearch('#search', '#table_body tr');
```

Comment: id should be unique. Currently "Performance" and "Personal Information" sections both have input element with id search and table body element with "table_body" that is the issue, update id like for Performance input "search_p" tbody as "table_body_p" and for Personal Information input "search_pi" tbody as "table_body_pi" then call function as setSearch("search_p", "table_body_p"); setSearch("search_pi", "table_body_pi");

Comment: nice! it works perfectly. thanks for enlightening.

Comment: Please accept my answer, so it will be helpful for others as well :)